# Did UIImageView isAnimating break in 4.0 SDK?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

The following code used to work when built with iOS 3.x.  Now with 4.x it doesn't work.  In other words, I can run two identical apps, on the same device, one built against a per-4.x release and the other with 4.3, and in the latter, isAnimating doesn't change values unless the screen is tapped or the orientation changes.

Here is the relevant code.  I started with a View based template in Xcode.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    iv.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer00.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer01.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer02.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer03.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer04.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer05.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer06.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer07.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer08.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer09.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer10.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer11.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer12.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer13.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer14.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer15.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer16.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer17.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer18.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer19.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer20.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer21.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer22.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer23.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer24.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer25.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer26.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer27.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer28.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer29.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer30.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer31.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer32.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer33.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer34.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer35.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer36.png"],                                      nil];
    iv.animationDuration = 5.0;
    iv.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [iv startAnimating];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(periodicallyUpdateView) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)periodicallyUpdateView {
    if ([iv isAnimating]) {
        NSLog(@"it is animating");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"it is NOT animating");
    }
}
```

Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Not related to the question, but sorry to say that this is a very bad code. You should have used a loop to create the array.

Comment: I didn't want to mess with a Mutable array.  Or did you have another way to do it?

Comment: I would prefer mutable array than this. Though its a personal choice.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on iOS 4.2 Simulator and 4.2.1 Device.

Comment: I just ran a few more tests (reducing the images to just three) and it looks like it takes at least a minute, sometime 4x what the expected delay should be, before isAnimating goes to NO.  If you don't see this, i.e., if the duration of the isAnimating == YES is exactly and only equal animationDuration*animationRepeatCount, then ?

Comment: My isAnimating is stuck as well. Long after the animation is over, it is still saying YES. (Hope it's not a bug on my side)

Comment: It looks like it might be in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This would be much much more efficient if you setup a timer. The problem you're facing may not be that UIImageView is broken but rather that the image view takes a very long time to load the animation.

I'd recommend something like this.

```
NSTimer *imageTimer;

int animationCount;

- (void)startAnimation
{
      imageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(switchImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)switchImage
{
       NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"timer%i" , animationCount];
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
       someImageView.image = image;
 }
```